# Are iron vases ok to keep dirt/plants?

Tags: indoors

Is an iron vase apt to keeping dirt for plants?  Or would it rust and leak from the bottom, so it shall be used only as a cache-pot?

I'd like to use this to grew a pothos (indoor).

Of course, I could always line the interior with a plastic bag. Is there any kind of plastic that is recommended or that should not be used?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Heavy-duty zipper freezer bags will do the trick formed into a saucer. You have to watch out for overwatering, but pothos likes it moist and may drink the saucer water back up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not so much the rust that's an issue (and yes, an unlined iron container will rust, but slowly), it's the lack of drainage. You never want to plant anything in any container that does not contain a drain hole. This includes the plastic bag you were thinking of using.

I have no way of knowing, of course, if you're also thinking of just lining the bottom of the container with gravel and planting above it (which used to be popular with container planting), but if you are, know that that creates a perched water table, which can drown the plant. See [here](https://gardenprofessors.com/container-planting-intuition-vs-reality/) for a brief discussion on this and a link to a paper that discusses it further.

If you want to use the container as simply a cache-pot, with a pot with drainage hole inside it, then just empty the leftover water from cache-pot about 15 minutes after watering the pothos. This will cut down on the incidence of rust and prevent leaks.